# Keeping Tasks Organized

Tags: pm-software, tasks, tracking

Currently where I am employed (as a developer) we have two programs to track tasks.

One tool (Ace Project) for larger project that groups several tasks below it, allows for some attachments, and commenting.  And is supposed to be used to plan projects, however, it's large, slow, and just a pain to use.

The other (RMTrack) is used for maintenance and feature additions to completed projects.  It's quicker, and closer to bug tracking.

We don't have defect tracking or bug tracking software... which I have tried to recommend.

However, the more I read about Project Management the more I like the idea of simply having a whiteboard with a grid for a project.  Names down the side, and SDLC groups across the top (Requirements, Design, Development, QA, Release...etc) and using sticky notes with the task, and moving it around on a whiteboard to keep track.

Unfortunately, there is no way that we will get whiteboards in the offices for this use.  Our work areas are too open, and "clean".

What I would like as an alternative is a virtual whiteboard we can setup and use in the same way.  With the added benefit of being able to attach links/documents to the sticky notes.  Track their movement.  And be very open and flexible so devs, pms, qa, managers, execs, can look at it, and even edit/move things if they want.

Is there any software out there like that already?

If I could find something and sell it as a way to organize the other two tools we use and be a portal into them, we might be able to better keep track of workloads and statuses.  And not run into the issues we currently do by trying to keep track of progress in excel spreadsheets scattered about.

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful

http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/scrumkanban-saas-tool

Comment: I think this is a valuable question, OP has outlined a practical project management problem and some constraints. Unfortunately, OP then asks for software recommendation.  Can we revise this so that question is "how do I solve this problem?"

Answer (score 5):

Trello is a new product anounced today, but it looks like it matches your requirements: http://blog.trello.com/launch/

Comment: Worth noting that this product has some familial relationship to Stack Exchange. :)

Comment: True, but I have no familial relationship.

Answer (score 3):

From what you describe [LeanKit Kanban](http://leankitkanban.com/Home/Features) should work well.

Your requirements are pretty typical for software Kanban boards so probably most of such application would be fine, although I propose LeanKit Kanban as one of most mature tools.

However, if the team is co-located a physical board will always trump the software one, so if possible I'd challenge your office rules in terms of having whiteboards.

Comment: We have remote devs, and a serious lack of wallspace preventing whiteboard use

Comment: Remote devs renders physical whiteboards less useful. However I know people who try to build a combo: physical board + software app even in such situations. Talking about little wall estate - my recent purchase is whiteboard on wheels - can be moved anywhere and doesn't need to be attached to wall. Anyway, LeanKit Kanban will do the job.

Comment: Thx Pawel, I didn't know that one.

Answer (score 3):

A nice software alternative to the whiteboard and post its is [Eylean](http://www.eylean.com/Features/ProjectManagement?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMaction). We have been using it for a while and quite enjoy it. The task board is very traditional and simple, but the additional features, integrations and reports is where the tool is great.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've seen to what you're suggesting is [AgileZen](http://agilezen.com/).

> AgileZen draws on an idea from lean manufacturing called kanban — a Japanese word that literally means visual card. In an AgileZen project, work is organized on a kanban board, which has a number of columns that represent the phases that work has to go through in order to be considered complete.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of agilezen.  Really easy to use and clean.

Answer (score 1):

I've used RallyDev in the past and I'm currently testing out VersionOne.  Both have free versions for small teams, etc.  In the end, paper seems to always hold people a bit more accountable simply due to its visibility.  It is up front and personal, where one can easily hide behind a monitor, forgetting to check in...takes discipline.

I have also been using FogBugz and this seems to be a great, lightweight tool to track your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing a business case for the last year for a pm software solution within our company. After  some research I have to say that there are very good solutions not only for agile pm but any model of project management, project execution respectively. Here are the best or at least what I have seen:
project insight (self hosted also possible)
attask (self hosted also possible)
clarizen (cloud only)
daptiv (daptiv)

All of the above also have issue tracking integrated what i understood is one of the key points you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using the Leankit Kanban product that has been suggested by Pawel. Works pretty well, allows hyperlinks to other systems (for example a Sharepoint site). One drawback is that it's externally hosted (I don't think they have an on-site license offer) and that might not be acceptable to your employer.

I've also seen a similar implementation in [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/en_UK/software/jira/) where a plugin provided the features you're looking for.

Cheers,
Wim

Comment: The implementation you are mentioning is called Greenhopper. http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/