# Electronic kanban board

Tags: pm-software, kanban

In my project we decided to use Kanban. We started with trello, the application is very nice but it has too few features. It doesn't support:

- WIP limits
- Class of service
- Multiple swim lanes

Which application can you recommend us to use? Are there any open source solutions?

Comment: Check out this question: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/829/any-desktop-kanban-board-application

This may answer your question.

Comment: Here you can find 20 kanban tools compared in a single table/post for your convenience: https://teamhood.com/kanban/best-kanban-board-tools/

Answer (score 5):

I like whiteboards.

Corkboards are nearly as good, but harder to reflect changes in process on, IMO. While pinned index cards don't fall off as often as stickies, if your stickies are falling off you might want to look at how long it's taking to get them off the board in the first place.

I've also seen cupboard doors, table tops and windows suborned into the role. These also work well.

If you have no board, no wallspace, no cupboards, table tops or windows then I guess you could use [LeanKitKanban](https://www.planview.com/products-solutions/products/leankit/get-leankit/) or [AgileZen](https://www.getapp.com/project-management-planning-software/a/agilezen/). They're free for 1 user and pretty cheap for large teams. I don't know of any open-source solutions.

Otherwise... whiteboard is the way forward.

Comment: We can't work on a real board since we have distributed/telecommuting team.

Comment: Fair play. We're using Jira with the GreenHopper plugin at the moment; that seems to work too.

Comment: +1 Also worth noting that most whiteboards are magnetic so you can use magnets not just stickies if stuff falling off is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Eylean Board](http://eylean.com/kanban). It is fully configurable, you can limit WIP, add as many swimlanes as you need, provides various reports including Lead and Cycle time. It also has a great User Interface. Download free trial [here](http://eylean.com/Download).

Comment: Hi Dovile, welcome back! If you're involved in this project somehow, I strongly recommend that you edit in a disclaimer as per our [faq - guidelines on self promotion](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). So far both of your answers on our site seem to promote this product.

Answer (score 1):

If cost is an issue for you, a decent open source option is [kanbanpad](https://www.kanbanpad.com/)

It is not as full featured as some of the other options, but it is free and I think it addresses your three concerns.

Answer (score 1):

My company develops http://toolsforagile.com which is a visualisation based tool. It supports WIP limits, swimlanes, classes of service, due dates etc etc. You can take a look at the features here - http://toolsforagile.com/silvercatalyst/features/ (scroll down the page for the kanban features)

Answer (score 1):

In a previous team, we used Jira with Greenhopper to track all development and most QA work in a team distributed across 2 continents & 3 cities.  It worked VERY well, so I highly recommend you look into it as a possibility.

The nice thing about Jira is its workflows are very customizable - so even though it is designed to work for Scrum teams out of the box, I'm sure you can make it do the job for Waterfall if you really wanted to.

http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/overview